# Is there any way to convert clojure spec to a readble json response?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have been using clojure.spec.alpha library for request body validation. Unfortunately, I after convert spec from s/explain-data to json, the given error is not quite clear:

```
{
"clojure.spec.alpha/problems": [
    {
        "path": [],
        "pred": [
            "clojure.core/fn",
            [
                "%"
            ],
            [
                "clojure.core/contains?",
                "%",
                "update"
            ]
        ],
        "val": {
            "where": {
                "key2": "value2"
            }
        },
        "via": [
            "name-service.delivery.spec/update-request"
        ],
        "in": []
    }
],
"clojure.spec.alpha/spec": "name-service.delivery.spec/update-request",
"clojure.spec.alpha/value": {
    "where": {
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way to handle different specs and return own custom response or maybe some library already do that?

Comment: Honourable mentions: https://github.com/bhb/expound https://github.com/metosin/malli#custom-error-messages

Comment: I understand you may have a specific need to go to json, but if you are serving a frontend that uses Clojurescript, have you considered EDN? The problem may go away if you use EDN.